# 固定長数値IDを推測しにく固定長文字列に暗号化する方法を探しています。

Tags: 暗号理論

ユーザーが他のユーザーのIDを推測しにくいように、システム内部で使っている数値のIDを固定長文字列に変換して画面側に送りたいのですが、適した暗号化方式はありすでしょうか？

イメージ
00001 ←→ AAAAB
00002 ←→ AAAAC
00003 ←→ AAAAD
00004 ←→ AAAAE
※これだと単純すぎますが、コスト優先で暗号化、複合化したいです。

Comment: 前提の話で恐縮ですが。どういうシステムかわかりませんが、一般的にユーザIDは推測されてもシステムに影響のない仕様にするべきです。もし暗号が突破されることがあった場合に致命的な傷になってしまいます。

Comment: コスト優先というのは、どのぐらいの手間でIDがばれてしまってもかまわない（諦めがつく）という事ですか？　
「画面側に送りたいのですが」の"画面側"というのは、どういう意味ですか？

Comment: 複数の事業者が使うプラットフォームサービスを作ろうとしています。 DBの設計でサロゲートキーを使っているので、１事業者が作るデータのIDが連番になりません。なので、事業者に見せるIDはランダム文字列に見えるようにしたいというのが理由の一つです。

Comment: あと、当然IDがバレても他の事業者のデータにアクセスできないよう認証をしますが、よりセキュリティを強固にするという意味でIDを推測しにくい文字列にしたいです。

Comment: DBにデータを登録する際に、ランダム文字列を生成してカラムに保存するアプローチも考えましたが、やりたい事に適した実行コストの低い暗号化方式があれば、そちらの方が良いと考えています。

Comment: すいません、画面側はブラウザの事です。
ブラウザの開発者ツールでIDを見られるのは構いませんが、プログラムでIDをループさせて攻撃されたりするのは避けたいです。

Comment: 個別のサービスの要件やリスク管理の話なのであまり言及しないほうがいいのでしょうが、ちょっとだけ。。ユーザIDを秘匿するという仕様はあまり聞いたことがないです。主要なWebサービスでもIDはそのまま表示されていることが多いと思います。そんなことよりもIDでループされて攻撃されるような穴をふさぐべきかなと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ID カラムに対して UUID を生成して保存しておき、それをユーザーに対しては表示するのが一般的な回答になるかと思います。

それはそうと、どうしても ID を一意に暗号化してユーザーに共有しなければならない場合、 AES256 あたりの、共通鍵暗号化を用いて暗号化/復号化するとして、ユーザーには暗号化結果を hexdump したものを送るようにすれば、ひとまずはそれっぽくはなりそうだな、とは思います。(対象の ID のレンジが 128bit 以下ならば、暗号化結果は32文字の[0-9a-f]の文字列ができあがります)